# PHP script execution under jquery and jscroll

Tags: jquery

PHP script execution under jquery and jscroll

I have searched for an answer but couldn't find one or I am unable to ask the right question...

Here is the problem:

1. I've implemented infinite scroll based on code from http://jscroll.com/ - it works great
2. I've implemented jquery to delete rows without page refresh and it also works but only on the first page where the jquery code is included. When the page expands by jscroll the jquery  is somehow invisible and it is not working.
3. I got really basic knowledge about javascript and jquery so I will apriciate if someone could provide me with the solution in form of code correction.

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form[class=delMsg]").submit(function() {
      var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
      var formDetails = $('#'+formID);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'del.php',
        data: formDetails.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {    
            $('#wynik_'+formID).html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
            $('#wynik_'+formID).html(error);   
        }
      });

      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML source code? If you add new forms dynamically you need to use the [``.on()``](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method, since ``$("[form[class=delMsg]")`` will only add listeners to the initial elements inside the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding `form` with `class delMsg` dynamically then you need to

Replace below code

```
$("form[class=delMsg]").submit(function() {
```

With this and try

```
$(document).on('submit', "form[class=delMsg]", function() { // Instead of document use the container id or class in which you are adding dynamic content
```

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <form class="delMsg">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit 0"/>
    </form>
</div>
<button id="add-form">Add Form</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', "form[class=delMsg]", function() {
        alert('form ' + $("form[class=delMsg]").index($(this)));
        return false;
    });

    $('#add-form').click(function() {
        $('#container').append('<form class="delMsg"><input type="submit" value="Submit ' + ($("form[class=delMsg]").length) +  '"></form>');
    });
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/6s8Q3/)**

Comment: I think you mean the other way around: ``$(document).on('submit', 'form[class=delMsg]', function(e){});``

Comment: I just edited the code and currently it starts with `$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('submit', "form[class=delMsg]", function() {` but still not working - even on the first (not expanded) site

Comment: The forms are generated dynamically with different id's

Comment: Make sure `forms` have `delMsg` as `class`

Comment: Form is defined as follow: `<form action='' class=delMsg id='form_delc521ba96b32df9a705997fb662683b3d' method='post'>`

Answer (score 0):

it is finally works and it works great!!! So... many thanks for your help :) 
I would like to explain why it was not worked at the first time. After small investigation I've discovered that if I put this form definition before some other form definition (with different id, class and used for other purposes) earlier in page code, it's starts working. I also discovered that this two form are the subject of one div but the first form was defined in a strange way like: `<from class=comment><div class=table_r><input type=submit></form><form class=delMsg><input type=submit></form></div>` So the definition of the first form was outside this div itself. When I moved `<form class=comment>` inside the div it starts working just like that :)
Maybe you will know why it's behave in such way - for me it is a magic :)

Once again thanks!